# How to understand this kind of data type in python (pyside2) : QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data8

Tags: python, pyside2

I am new to python. Just come across this "nested" data type as show in the image link below, which is kind of weird for me. How to define this kind of "type" manually?  It looks like enum, but not just simple enum class

```
from PySide2 import QtSerialPort

obj_databits = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data8
print(obj_databits)
```

[pycharm debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ULBR.jpg)

Try to find in the source code with no result.

Comment: It's an enum that describes the number of data bits used; see [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#DataBits-enum).

Comment: It's an internal enum type that's specific to PySide2: `type(QSerialPort.Data8).mro()` -> `[<class 'PySide2.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.DataBits'>, <class 'Shiboken.Enum'>, <class 'object'>]`. You cannot create one yourself, although PySide2 does provide `QtCore.QEnum` which will register a [Python Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) to the Qt meta-object system (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QEnum.html) for more details). In PySide6, *all* enums are defined as Python enums (and the same goes for PyQt6).